# developing for companies with individual dev account

Tags: ios, app-store

i have an individual dev account and a project from some company. would it be possible to develop an app for company (with the company name inside of app) and submit it in AppStore using my individual account? Would Apple allow that?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this question.

I do know that Apple has really really tedious business enrollment process (takes forever) so I would like to get this out of the way asap if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have the legal right to publish the app, I very much doubt that Apple will care.

What you need to bear in mind, though, is that it will be *your* name that appears in the App Store. Worse, it's difficult to transfer an app from developer account to developer account (usually involving removing it from sale and resubmitting as the new owner), so it's pretty important to get it right first time.

For what it's worth, I think the company should have their own developer account and you should submit from there.

Answer (score 1):

If the business (any client) want to control its application(s) (not have the app expire if you stop developing, have other developers work on it in the future, own the copyright, etc.), and have their name as seller of the app, they should enroll as a company in the iOS developer program, and have you submit the app under their account, even if that takes longer.  But it shouldn't take longer if they have all their paperwork (corporate documents, trademarks, email/website domains, company bank accounts, etc.) in order.